# Can i define a type to generic typescript object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I need an object that receives n properties of the same type. I have a similar code of this:

```
interface propsChild {
  a?: string,
  b?: string
}
//i make this interface to create an object with n propierties
interface Props{
  [key: string]: propsChild
}

//its works to create object, the typescript give me the tiping:
const myObject: Props = {
  p: {
    a: 'test'
  },
  p2: {
    b: 'test2'
  }
}

//but when i tried use this object, typescript dont know the props on this:
console.log(myObject.p) //works, but i dont have autocomplete
```

Its posible to create a type from "myObject"?

Comment: If you define `myObject: Props`, then this is expected behavior (`Props` says, that `a` may be undefined, therefore `myObject.p.a` may also be undefined, judging from the type). If you want to use the exact type, you could use [as const](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), however, then it isn't of the type `Props` anymore

Comment: You probably want `Props` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in its keys, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVgy5m), if you care about keeping track of these things.  If that approach works for you I can write up an answer (or find an existing question with that answer).  If not, please let us know what's missing.

Comment: yes, I wanted exactly that, tanks.